# I don't need a display, still "X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication." error

Tags: networking, ssh, xorg, login, x11-forwarding

I have a very simple problem, I have two users on a remote machine, user1 has administrative privileges and user2 does not. When I ssh from a local machine to the remote machine and login to user1 and then from there to user2, everything is fine. But if I login to user2 directly, I keep getting this message "X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication." no matter what! Adding `xauth` cookie didn't work, putting `X11Forwarding yes` didn't work either. So I tried `ssh user2@remotemachine` to login without any display requirements (honestly, I don't need it), but I am still getting this message, why?

The answer I need is to the question, "Why will just `ssh user2@remotemachine` show X11 error message on my terminal every few seconds? And how can I stop or suppress this message?"

Answer (score 1):

Honestly I had the same problem myself, and I've actually had the same problem over a number of years -- all with varying solutions.  As of 2019, I solved this problem this time by explicitly adding

```
X11UseLocalhost no
```

to the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file.  Restart server after making change.  Supposedly newer clients don't need this capability (hence the reason I mentioned 2019). YMMV

Comment: Thanks, will try that now, just a question, how do you restart the server without affecting any other background processes, running scripts etc?

Comment: So assuming your running Ubuntu or any Linux system that utilizes systemd I believe the command is: `sudo systemctl restart sshd`